# Null pointer Exception on retrieving values form database

Tags: mysql, database, nullpointerexception

```
package database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * This Class handles insertion and deletion of contact us details in to contact
 * us table
 *
 * @version 1.0.0 17 May 2013
 * @author Sarath Soman <nsarathsoman@gmail.com +919995189217>
 */
public class ContactUs {

    private Connection con;
    private PreparedStatement pst;
    private ResultSet rs;
    private String query;
    private final String ID = "id";
    private final String NAME = "name";
    private final String EMAIL_ID = "email_id";
    private final String CONTACT_NO = "contact_no";
    private final String QUERY = "query";
    private final String TIME_ZONE = "time_zone";
    private final String BEST_CALL_TIMING = "best_call_timing";
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allContacts = null;

    /*
     * Constructor Establishes database connection to con
     */
    public ContactUs() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        con = Database.dbConnect();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves all values in contact us  details 
     * @return 
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dbGetAll() throws SQLException {
        query = "select "+NAME+","+EMAIL_ID+","+CONTACT_NO+
                ","+QUERY+","+TIME_ZONE+","+BEST_CALL_TIMING+" from contact_us";
        ArrayList<String> contacts = null;
        pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            contacts.add(rs.getString(1));//this line shows null pointer exception
            contacts.add(rs.getString(2));
            contacts.add(rs.getString(3));
            contacts.add(rs.getString(4));
            contacts.add(rs.getString(5));
            contacts.add(rs.getString(6));
            allContacts.add(contacts);
            contacts.clear();
        }
        return allContacts;
    } 
}
```

This is the class which i defined to get data from a contact_us table in my mysql database but and as I have commented I get the null pointer exception in the 1st line inside the wile loop. I cannot find where I'm going wrong.

note: database has values

Comment: put a breakpoint and see if it is null or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList<String> contacts = null;` your `contacts` object remains null because of this line.
Try - `` `ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>(); ``

Comment: Thank you. private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allContacts = null; this was also null Now its working